# adding File to a String?

Tags: java, string, file

I just discovered this curious line of code, which compiles:

```
String a = (new File("")) + "f";
System.out.println(a);
```

Output:

```
f
```

I use jre 1.8_111 on Eclipse Neon.2 on Windows 10 Pro.

It only compiles with an empty String initializer, but I think it shouldn't, because the + operator isn't overloaded for File. Or is it?

I checked that `new File("")` isn't `null`, but its `filePath` and `status` are.

Any ideas why does it compile?

Comment: You can also concat objects with strings. Internally the `.toString()` method will be called.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Comment: You can concatenate anything with a string. That's what [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is a bad readable alternative to

```
File file = new File("c");
String a = file.toString() + "f";
```

Comment: @GregT: How relevant is that to the string concatenation operator, which is what you're asking about?